# The "there exists" quantifier and density in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is dense $\iff$ all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and their open sets $(x-r,x+r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. So if $A$ is an interval we have a number $y \in (a,b) \cap (x - r, x + r)$.

Often in proofs, this is used and stated like

"Let $A = (a,b)$. If $a \leq z \leq b$, then by density of $A$ and if $(a,b)$ is a dense subset, then there is a number $x$ such that $z < x < b$"

Now when we say "there exists" in quantifiers. How do we know there are "many" existence and where they are? Technically if there is only *one* number that satisfies the density condition, it is still true, so how we do know the number $x $ might exist $z < x < b$ but maybe not $a < x' <z$?

Answer (score 1):

Because the density property is true for all $r$. You can generate infinitely many points directly from the definition by considering a sequence of radii, $r_i$. First, take $r_0$ to be any number and find a point according to the definition (say $b_0$). Then take $r_1$ be $\frac{|x-b_0|}{2}$. By construction, $b_0$ doesn't fall into $(x-r_1,x+r_1)$ so the definition gives the existence of another number, call it $b_1$. And so on and so forth.

The upshot of this is that if a set, $A$, is dense at $x$, then for every number $r$ there are in fact infinitely many elements in the intersection $A\cap\{x-r,x+r\}$.